# How to close dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a grid that populates from a search event and I'd like the option of being able to close the grid by simply adding an X in the top right corner, similar to how you close any browser or window. I thought it would be as easy as adding the X, styling it to my liking and then creating an onclick event that would close or hide the grid... but I can't seem to get that working. Any help would be appreciated.

My JS is:

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid"); //FindTask
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore"); //FindTask
dojo.require("esri.tasks.find"); //FindTask

var findTask, findParams;
var grid, store;
var searchExtent;

function doFind() {

            //Show datagrid onclick of search button and resize the map div.
            esri.show(datagrid);
            dojo.style(dojo.byId("content"), "height", "83%");
            searchExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent ({
            "xmin":-9196258.30121186,"ymin":3361222.57748752,"xmax":-9073959.055955742,"ymax":3442169.390441412,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}
            });

            map.setExtent(searchExtent);

    //Set the search text to the value in the box
    findParams.searchText = dojo.byId("parcel").value;
            grid.showMessage("Loading..."); //Shows the Loading Message until search results are returned.
    findTask.execute(findParams,showResults);
  }

  function showResults(results) {
    //This function works with an array of FindResult that the task returns
    map.graphics.clear();
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([98,194,204]), 2), new dojo.Color([98,194,204,0.5]));


    //create array of attributes
    var items = dojo.map(results,function(result){
      var graphic = result.feature;
      graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
      map.graphics.add(graphic);
      return result.feature.attributes;
    }); 

    //Create data object to be used in store
    var data = {
      identifier: "Parcel Identification Number",  //This field needs to have unique values. USES THE ALIAS!!!
      label: "PARCELID", //Name field for display. Not pertinent to a grid but may be used elsewhere.
      items: items
    };

     //Create data store and bind to grid.
    store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data:data });
    var grid = dijit.byId('grid');
    grid.setStore(store);

    //Zoom back to the initial map extent
    map.setExtent(searchExtent);

  }

  //Zoom to the parcel when the user clicks a row
  function onRowClickHandler(evt){
    var clickedTaxLotId = grid.getItem(evt.rowIndex).PARCELID;
    var selectedTaxLot;

    dojo.forEach(map.graphics.graphics,function(graphic){
      if((graphic.attributes) && graphic.attributes.PARCELID === clickedTaxLotId){
        selectedTaxLot = graphic;
        return;
      }
    });
    var taxLotExtent = selectedTaxLot.geometry.getExtent();
    map.setExtent(taxLotExtent);
  }
```

and my HTML is:

```
<div id ="datagrid" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" splitter="true" region="bottom"
        style="width:100%; height:125px;">
        <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-id="grid"  id="grid" data-dojo-props="rowsPerPage:'5', rowSelector:'20px'">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th field="Parcel Identification Number" width="10%">
                        Parcel ID
                    </th>
                    <th field="Assessing Neighbornood Code" width ="20%">
                        Neighborhood Code
                    </th>
                    <th field="Property Class Code" width="10%">
                        Property Class
                    </th>
                    <th field="Site Address" width="100%">
                        Address
                    </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
    </div>
```

This is my best guess at what to add:

```
                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <div class="divOk" onclick="dijit.byId('tocDiv').hide();">
                        OK</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: i can't see what you have tried to achive you goal in the code.

Comment: Edited to include my attempt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up creating a work around for what I want by creating a new column and putting a close icon within the header. I connected it to an function so that when I click it, the grid closes and the map resizes:

```
function closeGrid() {
        esri.hide(datagrid);
        dojo.style("map", {"height": "100%"});
        }
```

HTML

```
<th field="" width="2%"> <div class="GridCloseIcon" title="Close Grid" onclick="closeGrid();"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
(assuming the OK line actually appears)

**HTML**

```
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <div class="divOk" onclick="hideGrid();">OK</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**JS**

```
    function hideGrid() {
        var widget = dijit.byId('datagrid');
        dojo.fadeOut({
            node: widget.domNode
        }).play();

        dojo.style(widget.domNode, 'display', 'none');
    }
```

Comment: alrigth, is already wondered how it would. I can tell you, that the declarative instanciation of the `DataGrid` is faky. The `DataGrid` in fact is made of various `div`'s but not any table (as you can see, if you look up the parsed sourcecode). I guess the easiest way would it be, to wrap the whole `DataGrid` in another `div` where you can place your `X`. Depending on you use case, it could also be worth it considering showing you `DataGrid` inside a `dijit.Dialog`-widget...